# CommandButton onClick

Tags: commandbutton, popup-window

I have a commandbutton at my page which open a new window. The url should be different for each item in the list, but if I put the url with the condition into the onclick the url doesnt work.

With flexible Condition:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Stats_In}" onclick="window.open('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!MSL.Id}')" value="Download" reRender="Dummy">
```

It open a new window but doesn't work
https://OUR_DOMAIN.cs87.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=a068E0000045JaOQAU

Hard coded file:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!Stats_In}" onclick="window.open('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P8E000004Ygm4UAC')" value="Download" reRender="Dummy">
```

It open an new window and works fine.
https://OUR_DOMAIN.cs87.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P8E000004Ygm4UAC

If you can see, the url is a bit different, not working my.salesforce.com --> working content.force.com. How is that possible? Can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"aXX" Id values are custom objects, while "00P" Id values are Attachment records. You will need to get the correct Id value in order to use servlet.FileDownload.